# iAds: Why doesn't CCGLView *eaglView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] work?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, iad

I've been running through a good Cocos2d tutorial to implement iAds and am close to getting it implemented (I get iAd messages from the console)...

I keep coming back to this Warning on:

```
CCGLView *eaglView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];
```

*"Instance method '-openGLView' not found..."*

I think it has something to do with the switch from calling GLView to CCGLView (cocos2d)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using type `CCGLView`, I guess you are using cocos2d-iphone 2.x, while 1.x doesn't have `CCGLView` but have `EAGLView`.

In 1.x usually we access the property `openGLView` to get the OpenGL view object:

```
EAGLView *eaglView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];
```

In 2.x, `CCDirector` class doesn't have such a property. Instead, `CCDirector` is now a subclass of `UIViewController` on iOS (and `NSObject` on Mac OS X). So, if you want to get the OpenGL view object on iOS, just do this:

```
CCGLView *ccglView = (CCGLView *)[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view];
```

since `view` is a property of `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thanks.  I know your answer is correct but I get "Incompatible pointer types initializing "CCGLView with an expression of type 'UIView'"...

Comment: @JimRota I guess you can safely cast it to a `CCGLView *` although the property `view` has a `UIView *` type. I cannot confirm this since I am working with 1.x, if you worry about whehter it is `CCGLView` object, test it with `isMemberOfClass:` method.

Comment: After a bit more research the following seems to work.   CCGLView *ccglView = (CCGLView *)[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view]; [self.view addSubview:ccglView];

Comment: Glad to know that. I've revised my answer accordingly.